# ¿Como leer los atributos de las etiquetas xml utilizando QXmlStreamReader?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

estoy trabajando con archivos xml, utilizando la Liberia de QT. El problema que se me presenta es siguiente:  no se como leer los atributos de las etiquetas xml utilizando QXmlStreamReader.

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wells>
    <number-wells value="3"/>   
    <wells-info>
        <row well-number="1" nodes="2" well-name="0.00000" Krg="">
        <row well-number="1" nodes="2" well-name="0.00000" Krg="">      
        <row well-number="1" nodes="2" well-name="0.00000" Krg="">
    </wells-info>
    <wells-direction>
        <row well-number="1" i="5" j="5" k="1" idir="1">
        <row well-number="2" i="5" j="5" k="1" idir="1">
        <row well-number="3" i="5" j="5" k="1" idir="1">
    </wells-direction>      
</wells>
```

De acuerdo a lo que estuve leyendo por algunos lados plante lo siguiente:

```
xml.setDevice(&archivo);
QXmlStreamAttributes atributos;
while(!xml.atEnd()){
    qDebug() << xml.readNext();
    if(xml.isStartElement()){
        QString etiqueta = xml.name().toString();
        if(etiqueta == "number-wells"){
            atributos = xml.attributes();
            foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &att, atributos) {
                qDebug() << "atributo" << att.name() << att.value();
            }
         }
         if(etiqueta == "wells-info"){
            qDebug() << "etiqueta: " << etiqueta;
            while(xml.readNextStartElement()) {
                if(etiqueta == "row"){
                    qDebug() << "etiqueta: " << etiqueta;
                    atributos = xml.attributes();
                    foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &att, atributos) {
                        qDebug() << "atributo" << att.name() << att.value();
                    }
                }
                else xml.skipCurrentElement();
            }
        }
    }
    xml.readNext();
} //end WHILE*/
if(xml.hasError()){
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","No se ha podido leer el archivo "+fileNameWell);
}
```

Solo me esta mostrando lo siguiente:

> 2
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> etiqueta:  "wells-info"
>
> QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 986, resource id:
>   17307926, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0

¿Qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(xml.isEndElement())
  { xml.readNext(); }
xml.readNext();
```

Es decir, si estás en la etiqueta de cierre pasas a la siguiente... Que será la de apertura... para seguidamente pasar a la siguiente etiqueta... yo te diría que puedes quitar el `if` completo.

---

**EDITO**

Sacado de la [documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readNextStartElement) del método `readNextStartElement` de la clase  `QXmlStreamReader`:

> The current element is the element matching the most recently parsed start element of which a matching end element has not yet been reached. When the parser has reached the end element, the current element becomes the parent element.

Resumiendo:

> Este método busca el final del elemento actual y a continuación se pone a buscar el siguiente elemento.

Tu pretendes leer la lista de hijos y este método no te va a servir en absoluto. Tienes que iterar de forma similar a como lo haces en el primer nivel:

```
if(etiqueta == "wells-info"){
    qDebug() << "etiqueta: " << etiqueta;
    while(xml.readNext()) {
        QString etiqueta = xml.name().toString();
        if(etiqueta == "row" && xml.isStartElement() )
        {
            qDebug() << "etiqueta: " << etiqueta;
            atributos = xml.attributes();
            foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &att, atributos) {
                qDebug() << "atributo" << att.name() << att.value();
            }
        }
        if(etiqueta == "wells-info")
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si he corregido esa parte. Pero el problema continua, es decir haciendo una traza, se que acá entra `while(xml.readNextStartElement())` . Pero obvia después de esta parte.  La verdad que no se que estaré haciendo mal.

Comment: @marcosvasquez piensa que la lectura de cada etiqueta deberían tener el mismo código y en tu caso es distinto. Ahora mismo no tengo pc. Prueba a sacar por la consola el nombre de cada etiqueta leída

Comment: Mira, lo que me imprime es lo siguiente: `atributo "value" "3"
"wells-info"`. Hasta ahi llega el bucle. Que podra ser?

Comment: @marcosvasquez Si te fijas el último elemento impreso se corresponde con la nueva etiqueta... mira a ver en qué momento imprimes ese valor porque ahí es donde estás perdiendo el nodo

Comment: voy a modificar el codigo que planteo, agregando lo que imprime asi se entiende mejor.

Comment: @marcosvasquez revisa la respuesta que la he editado... aunque como no tengo ni el XML ni tu código no puedo compilarlo ni probarlo

Comment: gracias por la solución, si evidentemente estaba haciendo un recorrido inadecuado.  Una aclaración, fíjate que en el código que me propones volves a definir los siguiente `QString etiqueta = xml.name().toString();`.  Debería hacer una actualización de la variable ya que se estaba definida anteriormente. Saludos.

Comment: @marcosvasquez no es un error... son dos variables independientes con vida distinta... realmente esto tendría que hacerse en una función independiente para aislar las diferentes capas de código